# Android bluetooth: Threads vs BroadcastReceiver problems

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

He implemented the Bluetooth connection from Arduino receiving data in Android without problems. Seller Amarino wore the Listener I did a very nice and I worked perfectly. The problem started when I realized that I had installed apk Amarino was necessary and acted as my application service. This obviously is a pain having to have installed an external application, so I set to work to find solutions.

The first thing I did was look for the library called Amarino Embed supposed to not need to run the application apk. The website is not very up to date and get out after thousands of examples and things did not work. Anyway, I went up the bluetooth notifications like Amarino and between that made ​​me very funny and did not work, I went to plan B.

Plan B was to implement it according to the Android documentation, which I have read and tested extensively implementase told me what a Thread to separate the execution of the main thread and also using a Handler. At first I thought that if it worked and it all sorted and I would implement this I saw online (I put loose parts):

```
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private static String address = "00:12:10:17:02:24";
private Handler h;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    txtArduino = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);   // for display the received data from the Arduino

    h = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
           case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:    // if receive massage
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1); // create string from bytes array
            sb.append(strIncom);    // append string
            int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");    // determine the end-of-line
            // Log.d("CADENA: ", "SB:  " + sb);
            if (endOfLineIndex > 0) { // if end-of-line,
            String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);   // extract string
                   sb.delete(0, sb.length());   
                   //Log.d("CADENA MAXIMA: ", "CM: " + sbprint);// and clear
                   String[] cadenaSepara = sbprint.split(",");
                   if(cadenaSepara != null) {
                    Log.d("TAMAÑO: ", "TAM: " + cadenaSepara.length);
                   }
                txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + sbprint);        // update TextView
               }
            //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
            break;
    }
       };
};     
   btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    // get Bluetooth adapter
   checkBTState();
}

 @Override
public void onResume() {
       BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
       btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
       btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
       btSocket.connect();
       mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
       mConnectedThread.start();
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
      private final InputStream mmInStream;
      private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
InputStream tmpIn = null;
OutputStream tmpOut = null;

// Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
// member streams are final
try {
     tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
     tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
 } catch (IOException e) { }

mmInStream = tmpIn;
mmOutStream = tmpOut;

//Log.d("THREAAAAAAAAD: ", "THREAAAAAAAAD: ");
}

public void run() {
       byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
       int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

       // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
       while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Log.d("BYTEEEES: ", "BIITES: " + bytes);// Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget(); // Send to message queue Handler
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
}
<code>
```

And this is the kind BROADCAST somewhat simplified and omitting the internal interface MindListenerTWO:

`<pre>
public class MindInterfaceTWO extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static BluetoothDevice dispositivo;
    private static List<MindListenerTWO> listeners = new ArrayList<MindListenerTWO>();

    public void addListener(MindListenerTWO mindListener) {
listeners.add(mindListener);
if (listeners != null && !listeners.isEmpty())
//context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
     }

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     //String accion = intent.getAction();
     //Log.d("DEBUG:", "LLEGAAAAAA AQUIIIII");
     //dispositivo = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
     //dispositivo.getAddress();
     Log.d("LLEGA: ", "AQUIIIIIIIIIII");

     // Here's what it did with AMARINO
     String data = null;

     // Esta cadena (que no se usa) simplemente muestra la direccion del
     // Bluetooth desde que se ha
     // enviado la informacion
     // final String address =
     // intent.getStringExtra(AmarinoIntent.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

     // Es el tipo de dato que se ha añadido al intento
     final int dataType = intent.getIntExtra(
     AmarinoIntent.EXTRA_DATA_TYPE, -1);
     Log.d("DATAAAAAAS ANTES DE ENTRAR: ", "DATOS: ");
     // Esto comprueba que es String en Android y char[] en Arduino para
     // que sean correctos los datos
     if (dataType == AmarinoIntent.STRING_EXTRA) {
data = intent.getStringExtra(AmarinoIntent.EXTRA_DATA);
Log.d("DATAAAAAA: ", "DATOS: " + data);
// Formato de los datos recibidos:
// signal strength, attention, meditation, delta, theta, low
// alpha, high alpha, low beta, high beta, low gamma, high gamma"
String[] datos = data.split(",");
if (data != null) {
signal = Integer.valueOf(datos[0]);
launchNewSignal(signal);
                 }
         }
<code>`

Ultimately, what I want is that I get the signal with the broadcast and to capture the data. I know it's a little roll comentártelo everything here but hey, I was a little crazy. Greetings, thanks!

(Sorry but I can not be okay in the post code)